# Why is my feature space so large and how to add clusters as features?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I used the cluster_centers_ attribute from sklearn.cluster.KMeans to make a scatter plot of the centers of my clusters. The method was identical to http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-kmeans-silhouette-analysis-py.

What does it mean if my range is 10's of 1000's rather than 10 like in the demo? I cannot seem to find sklearn documentation on cluster_centers_ that is more than a sentence.

Six Clusters Silhouette Score and Cluster Visualization

[image]

Lastly, assuming my clusters are valuable features, where is there a demo of how to add these as features to my dataset?

```
model=KMeans(n_clusters=k)
model_labels = model.fit_predict(X)
silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(X, model_labels)
...
ax2.scatter(X.weekday, X.Weekday, marker='.', s=30, lw=0, alpha=0.7,
            c=colors)
centers = model.cluster_centers_
ax2.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1],
            marker='o', c="white", alpha=1, s=200)
for i, c in enumerate(centers):
    ax2.scatter(c[0], c[1], marker='$%d$' % i, alpha=1, s=50)
```

My code only differs from the sklearn demo in that I use my own 4500 1-D rows of close weekdays (ranging 0-6) and another 4500 1-D rows of start weekdays (ranging 0-6), rather than the two 500 1-D rows that sklearn uses. I have 24 columns of data and pick these two rows.

The answer for the second part is:

```
clus_train.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
cluslist = list(clus_train['index'])
model6 = KMeans(n_clusters=6)
model6.fit(clus_train) # has cluster assingments based on using 6 clusters
labels = list(model6.labels_)
newlist=dict(zip(cluslist, labels))
newclus=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(newlist, orient='index')
newclus.columns = ['cluster']
newclus.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
merged_train = pd.merge(clus_train, newclus, on='index')
```

Comment: [mcve] please! How do you expect us to know what you did, what data you used?

Comment: @JulienBernu there is not much special about the code, it's a question about what feature space means in sklearn, and a question about how to use sklearn clusters to make features.

Comment: Well the clusters are positions living in the space of your data. If your data is in [0, 1000), all points in these interval are valid clusters. If your samples are all within [0, 1), it would be a bad sign if some cluster would be 500. And the second question is just basic numpy-usage. Grab the docs. *A general remark:* while sklearn implements many useful algorithms and provide a lot of rules and basic knowledge within the user-guides, it does not teach you the theory of that specific algorithm in detail. You need to do your research somewhere else to understand kmeans.

Comment: @sascha What I didn't know was that you can get labels of the clusters, having run a model in KMeans for n_clusters=x, where x is your most appropriate number of clusters from the Elbow Method. Then you can eventually merge this into your dataframe. It's not simple numpy!

Comment: @sascha Your first part explanation is great though!